# checkout_cart_product_add_after fired only once for grouped product

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, multiple-add-to-cart

I m observeing `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event to modify quote item.

But it seems it fired only once no matter how many qty or item i have added from detail page.

My goal is to change each item with add custom option and change price.

[Group product added with all the sub product](http://prntscr.com/np969o)

I am missing anything here or should I observe another event to make a change in quote item.

Comment: I am having same problem, let me know the solution also. i am able to get the first quote_item only from that group.

Comment: Did you ever find a sollution for this?